# How to stop animation at end of cycle?

Tags: android, animation, animationutils

I have an ImageView that I'm rotating for use as a loading animation. Once my data is loaded, I try to stop the animation, but instead of cycling to the end and then stopping, the animation goes to a halfway point, then stops, and then the image snaps back to its original state, which looks pretty ugly.

Here is what I've tried:

Option 1:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshImage);
if (iv != null) {
    iv.clearAnimation();
}
```

Option 2:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshImage);
if (iv != null && iv.getAnimation() != null) {
    iv.getAnimation().cancel();
}
```

Option 3:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshImage);
if (iv != null && iv.getAnimation() != null) {
    iv.getAnimation().setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            animation.cancel();

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}
```

The end result is the same in all three cases. How do I rotate the image and have it end up back where it started?

Edit:

Some further information: My rotation animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="1000"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="360" />
```

How I start the animation:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.refreshImage);
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
iv.startAnimation(rotation);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the animation repeatcount to infinite before you start it, then when the action finishes, set the repeatcount of the animation to 0. The animation will finish the current loop and the stop without the jump that you want to avoid.

```
//How you start
Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
          rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
iv.startAnimation(rotation);

//You do your stuff while it spins
...

//You tell it not to repeat again
rotation.setRepeatCount(0);
```

It's important that you first set it to `Animation.INFINITE` (or -1 since they do the same) and then to `0`, if you set it to `1000` for instance, then it wont stop for some reason according to my testing.

Comment: Some of my animations are still a little jumpy, but it works for most of them, thanks!

Comment: @Catherine it may look jumpy for animation sets where multiple things are occurring at the same time, haven't tested it but for simple animations this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the nice trick. It would have been better Android provided an api stopAfterCycleCompletion() or something like that.

Comment: This may have worked 5 years ago, but now the animation simply stops in its tracks.

Comment: Made it a community wiki since it's a somewhat popular answer in case someone else wants to update it. I'm a bit out of the loop currently

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`rotation.setFillAfter(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter%28boolean%29);

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score -2):

iv.clearAnimation(); to stop the animation